# Android studio not opening (Ionic)

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uRej.png)
When I trying to build my ionic app ("ionic cap build android")
Android studio didn't open at all
there's no error indication
currently using Android studio giraffe

All path/environment done(java,sdk)
Emulator inside android studio already installed (android)
already installed capacitor

Comment: Does `ionic capacitor open android` works? how about opening android studio manually?

Comment: sorry for late reply, it's not working and no errors provided. For now I open the folder manually in android studio so I kinda hassle for me though/